# Selection state of upvote/downvote buttons on Meta isn't obvious

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

On Meta, the upvote/downvote buttons are gray.  It's not obvious whether dark gray indicates that the button is selected or light gray indicates that the button is selected.  It's complicated by the fact that the unselected star is in-between the two other grays, but closer to the unselected dark gray.

[image: Screenshot of upvote/downvote arrows]

Comment: this will be updated in coming release.

Answer (score 2):

The default background on the vote arrows is now clear:

[image]

Comment: Should the unselected star be hollow as well to be consistent?

Comment: @200_success Good question. Right now the star highlight is yellow. I think an empty star/grey star when chosen would make sense on meta personally, but it ain't my department, so I'll ask Pawel. :)